# How to edit / define Jenkinsfile text within Jenkins job?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

Sometimes it is not possible (yet) to put `Jenkinsfile` into git repository.

I think it was possible to edit/define `Jenkinsfile` content just within job,
but with latest Jenkins, I cannot find such support.

[image]

Now I see only filename configuration.

Answer (score 0):

OK, just be sure to select usual Pipeline project and not Multibranch pipeline

[image]